# v-model and v-for can't update the iteratives variables on the input radio buton

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

i need a help for some v-model and v-for error , i can't set the value of radio buton , and i can't pass the value of radio buton ( who is get in my backend )

The error is :

"'v-model' directives cannot update the iteration variable 'etat_commande' itself"

I used vuejs3

here is my code :

```
                        <div
                            v-for="etat_commande in etat_commandes"
                            :key="etat_commande.code"
                            
                        >
                                <input type="radio"
                                    :value="etat_commande.code"
                                    v-model="etat_commande"
                                    :disabled="!canWrite('etat_commande')"
                                    @change="onChange('etat_commande')"
                                    name="radio">
                                {{ etat_commande.label }}
                        </div>

                    <script>
                    export default {

                        data() {
                            return {
                                etat_commandes: [],
                              
                            
                            }
                        },
                    }


                         computed: {
                              etat_commande:{
                                   set(code) {
                                      console.log("etat_commande.code", code);
                                          if(code !== "") {
                                                  this.articleStore.article.etat_commande = { code };
                                                } else {
                                                    this.articleStore.article.etat_commande = null;
                                                }
                                            },

                                            get() {
                                                const code = this.articleStore.article?.etat_commande?.code;
                                                return code != null && code != undefined ? String(code) : "";
                                            }
                                        },
                                    }
                    </script>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68655002/6478501